# how can I convert a long string with values separated by commas into a list of strings of the values

Tags: python, split

I am using python 3.4.2 and visual studio code  i am a total newbie
I have been trying to search for the answer, but probably don't know enough to search for the right answers.  I am trying to learn python and this is my learning tool.  It is a redo of a program I wrote in basic in the early 80's on a TRASH32 where I couldn't access a data file and had to enter the data by hand.

I want to open a file that is a long string with the items (spaces, str, int) 
separated with commas.  (example:"EMD","20170820", 1, 1,,870,"D",,"N","BUN",")  but about 450,000 charaters long.  I am trying to make a list of strings separated at the commas so that I can call them up, list[0:6] returns 870, ect..
I have tried-

```
lines = tuple(open('filename','r'))   # all in only one string.
    print(list)                       # this showed whole file was read.
```

I tried-

```
with open('filename'):      -this opens file as a list of strings, but only                                                              
    list = line.split(',')    the last third of the file is in the list. 
    print(list)            # this showed whole file was read.
```

I tried-

```
with open('filename',('r'))as f:  -this also opens the file as a list of 
   reader = csv.reader(f)         strings, only the last third or so of the 
   list = list(reader)           file is in the list.
print(list)            # this showed whole file was read.
```

I guess my question is, what can I do with the 'with open(filename')code' to make the whole file accessible so that I can work with it?  Below is a sample of my code and an example of the results. If that is not feasible, how can I convert a long string with values separated by commas into a list of strings 
of the values.

```
import sys
import os
import csv

with open('c:/code/EMD0820.DRF'):
    for line in open('c:/code/EMD0820.DRF'):
         list = line.split(',') 
         #print(list)                  # this shows entire file came thru

str_list=str(list)
print (str_list[0:30])                    # this prints out 29 characters 1a
#print(line[0:5])                         # this prints "EMD"    1b
#print(list)                              # this prints lists but only from page 117 of 119 to the end.   1c

print (list[1:15])                        # prints first 14 strings starting where print(line[0:5]) did. 1d
```

results

```
1a  ['"EMD"', '"20170820"', '11', 

1b  "EMD"

1c  ["EMD","20170820",11, 8,,1320,"D",,"C","BUN","Clm2500n2l",6000,............to end of file]

1d [,"20170820",11, 8,,1320,"D",,"C","BUN","Clm2500n2l",6000,2500,2500,66.86]
```

Comment: It is hard for me to understand your problem. please make sure to put here precisely the code you have tried - parts of the code here are invalid and cause runtime errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('/path/to/file') as f:
    content = f.read().replace('\n', ',')
    content_list = content.split(',')

print(content_list)
```

Comment: worked.  file length 127716 both beginning and end are there

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file into an object in memory. Then you can call `split()`.

Try:

```
with open('c:/code/EMD0820.DRF') as f:
    read_file = f.read()
    l = read_file.split(",")
```

Comment: worked.  file length 127627 both beginning and end are there